# NameError: uninitialized constant Faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to run a simple bundle exec rake db:seed for my database in Rails 4.  However, when running it, I get the following output:

```
********-C02MGBVJFD57:myapp ***********$ bundle exec rake db:seed
Your Gemfile lists the gem factory_girl_rails (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Faker
/Users/**********/workspace/myapp/db/seeds.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/**********/workspace/myapp/db/seeds.rb:15:in `times'
/Users/**********/workspace/myapp/db/seeds.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/**********/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
/Users/**********/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `load_seed'
/Users/**********/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my seeds.rb file:

```
User.create!(
  name:                  "Example User",
  email:                 "example@railstutorial.org",
  password:              "foobar",
  password_confirmation: "foobar",
  admin:                 true
)

99.times do |n|
  name     = Faker::Name.name
  email    = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(
    name:                  name,
    email:                 email,
    password:              password,
    password_confirmation: password
  )
end
```

Line 16 is:

```
name = Faker::Name.name
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the faker gem?

Comment: I have the faker gem under my gemfile in group :test do

Comment: Were you running `rake db:seed` in the test environment? Assuming you are running it in development, you need to add it to your development group as well.

Comment: ok that worked; sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: It's not a waste of time if you learned something.  Might be worthwhile to add your own answer at the bottom saying something like `rake db:seed` runs in the `development` environment.  If you're using `Faker` in your seeds, make sure it's in both the `development` and `test` groups.

Answer (score 52):

Just faced similar issue - I was running

```
rails g model model_name
```

and getting the error:

```
uninitialized constant Faker (NameError)
```

Problem was due to fact, that I had gem added to `test` group.

Placing it into `development` **and** `test` group solved the problem:

```
group :development, :test do
  # ...
  gem 'faker'
  # ...
end
```

Comment: yup... :face_palm:

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue while writing rspec and adding `require 'faker'` in spec file solved it.

Comment: in the individual tests spec file or in the rails_helper.rb file?

Comment: I had to use require 'faker' in rails console in development environment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added `gem 'faker'` in the Gemfile. Then I run `bundle install` to get the gem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As per official faker documentation, it said:

> Note: if you are getting a uninitialized constant Faker::[some_class]
> error, your version of the gem is behind the one documented here. To
> make sure that your gem is the one documented here, change the line in
> your Gemfile to:

```
gem 'faker', :git => 'https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker.git', :branch => 'main'
```

But the problem still persist with mine app, since I have done this and I am getting the error again, but only when try to run the migrations to heroku:

```
heroku run rails db:migrate db:seed
```

When I run the command locally I do not have the problem and migrations and seeds are executed.