# Uninitialized constant FAKER when "seeding" db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I am trying to seed a db using the gem faker but keep getting:

```
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialised constant FAKER
```

when running `rails db:seed`

Initially I though it was a problem with my project so I created a new clean one, added  `gem 'faker'` to the Gemfile, ran 'bundle install` but I have the same error.

**db/seed.rb**

```
50.times do
  name = FAKER::NAME.name
  Item.create(name: name)
end
```

I also tried to add `require 'faker'` to the beginning of the `seed.rb` file but nothing changed.

I checked all the other answers on Stack Overflow, but they don't seem to solve my problem.

Any idea?

Ruby: 2.4.0p0

Rails: 5.0.1

EDIT: The gem is not installed in the test group as suggested on
[NameError: uninitialized constant Faker ; Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452632/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-faker-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: the module is named `Faker` not `FAKER`.

Comment: yeah... :( I should get some rest. Thanks @Anthony